# R optparse error with command line arguments

Tags: r, optparse

For some reason, the `optparse` usage in this script breaks:

`test.R`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
library("optparse")

option_list <- list(
    make_option(c("-n", "--name"), type="character", default=FALSE,
                dest="report_name", help="A different name to use for the file"),
    make_option(c("-h", "--height"), type="numeric", default=12,
                dest = "plot_height", help="Height for plot [default %default]",
                metavar="plot_height"),
    make_option(c("-w", "--width"), type="numeric", default=10,
                dest = "plot_width", help="Width for plot [default %default]",
                metavar="plot_width")
)

opt <- parse_args(OptionParser(option_list=option_list), positional_arguments = TRUE)
print(opt)

report_name <- opt$options$report_name
plot_height <- opt$options$plot_height
plot_width <- opt$options$plot_width

input_dir <- opt$args[1] # input directory
```

I get this error:

```
    $ ./test.R --name "report1" --height 42 --width 12 foo
Error in getopt(spec = spec, opt = args) :
  redundant short names for flags (column 2).
Calls: parse_args -> getopt
Execution halted
```

However, if I remove the `"-h"` from this line:

```
make_option(c("--height"), type="numeric", default=12,
                    dest = "plot_height", help="Height for plot [default %default]"
```

It seems to work fine;

```
$ ./test.R --name "report1" --height 42 --width 12 foo
$options
$options$report_name
[1] "report1"

$options$plot_height
[1] 42

$options$plot_width
[1] 12

$options$help
[1] FALSE


$args
[1] "foo"
```

Any ideas what might be going on here?

I am using R 3.3.0 and `optparse_1.3.2` (`getopt_1.20.0`)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `-h` flag is reserved by optparse (which is described as a feature of optparse which is not in getopt,  [from the getopt.R source file on Github](https://github.com/trevorld/getopt/blob/1ae9c1db175d1d4894dab8a9673203e66a2fc541/R/getopt.R#L62-L67)):

> Some features implemented in optparse package unavailable in getopt:
>
> 2. Automatic generation of an help option and printing of help text when encounters an "-h"

Therefore, when the user specifies `-h`, the [sanity check](https://github.com/trevorld/getopt/blob/1ae9c1db175d1d4894dab8a9673203e66a2fc541/R/getopt.R#L232-L238) for uniqueness of flags fails. The [issue tracker](https://github.com/trevorld/optparse/issues/) does not seem to have any mention of the need to create a better error message for this case, however.

Finally, note that optparse seems to be invoking getopt, as they have the same author.